# Problem with flex column direction for ul elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a menu that I created using Flexbox. As you can see:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vdcmey8)

When I hover on (( sample page ok )), the menu will open. Every `ul` element is a flex item, that is ok, but the problem is, if `ul` element height was tall, the flex item should move to next column. I need it to start from the previous `ul` element and its `li` elements move to the next column when needed. Actually, I need `ul` element 4 start after `ul` element 3 not in next column.

I can't change HTML because this is an WP nav element.

```css
.niki-menu {
    background-color: #616161;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 hsla(0,0%,44%,.05);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    transition: top .3s;
 position:relative;
  direction:rtl;
  text-align:right;
}
.niki-menu-line {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #000;
}
.niki-menu-list {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #616161;
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.niki-menu-list-promotions {
    position: relative;
}
.niki-menu-list-items > .niki-menu-list-items-item, .niki-menu-list-items > .c-navi-new-list__promotion-item, .niki-menu-list-promotions > .niki-menu-list-items-item, .niki-menu-list-promotions > .c-navi-new-list__promotion-item {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item>li>a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px 9px 7px;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 25px;
    max-width: 116px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item>li>a {
    max-width: 140px;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item>li>a {
    max-width: unset;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.833;
    padding: 10px 20px 9px;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item>li:hover>a {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
 color:#fff;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item>li:hover>a:before {
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #ef5661;
 transform: scaleX(1);
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 display: none;
 right: 0;
 left: unset;
 z-index: 12;
 width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
 height: 410px;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 19px 24px 45px 280px;
 border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-width: 1280px;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li:hover>ul {
 background: #fff;
 display: inline-flex !important;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li {
    display: inline-flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: flex-start;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: 31.538px !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li.break:after {
    content: '';
 height: 400px;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li a {
 overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #1ca2bd;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 32px;;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li a:before {
    content: "\E00F";
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
 top:3px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    color: #1ca2bd;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.833;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li a:hover span {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #1ca2bd;
    font-weight: 700
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li>ul {
 position: relative;
 top: auto;
 display: inline-flex;
 right: auto;
 left: auto;
 z-index: 12;
 width: 100%;
 box-shadow: none;
 height: auto;
 background-color: transparent;
 padding: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 overflow: visible;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 350px;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li:hover ul {
    display: flex;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li>ul>li {
    width:100%;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li>ul>li a {
    color: #6a6a6a;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 2.27;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding-right: 20px;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li>ul>li a:before {
    display:none;
}
.niki-menu-list-items-item li>ul>li>ul>li a:hover {
    font-weight: 700;
 border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="niki-menu">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <ul class="niki-menu-list">
                <li class="niki-menu-list-items">
                    <ul id="menu-main" class="niki-menu-list-items-item">
                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home current-menu-ancestor menu-item-has-children">
                            <a href=" ">sample page ok</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" style="height:410px">
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href=" my-account/"><span class="menu-image-title">ul element</span></a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" blog/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" checkout/">sample page</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" blog/"><span class="menu-image-title">ul element</span></a></li>
                                <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children">
                                    <a href=" %"><span class="menu-image-title">ul element 3</span></a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" order-tracking/">sample page</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children">
                                    <a href=" my-account/"><span class="menu-image-title">ul element 4</span></a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li class="nikititle menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-20 current_page_item"><a href=" ">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" blog/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" my-account/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" checkout/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" blog/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class="nikititle menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-20 current_page_item"><a href=" ">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" checkout/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" sample-page/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" cart/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-20 current_page_item"><a href=" ">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" shop/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" compare-page/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" compare/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" track-submit/">sample page</a></li>
                                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" order-tracking/">sample page</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" sample-page/">sample page</a></li>
                        <li class=" menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href=" shop/">sample page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: your jsfiddle link is broken

Comment: i can't add complete link with http in editor!!

Comment: @saeidi You need to provide inline code and then you can post your fiddle at the end, you can't just put the fiddle alone

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2vdcmey8

Comment: thanks @Matt for edit

Comment: Bit unclear what you actually want to achieve here; but you might want to look into CSS Columns rather than flexbox for this. (_“I can't change HTML because this is an WP nav element.”_ - yes you could, that’s why the ability to customize the menu output with a custom Nav Walker exists.)

Comment: @misorude i said i can't because i don't know how can i do this and think change css is better and easier for do this.